# How to detect if I'm running in AWS Lambda environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to detect if my code is getting executed in AWS Lambda environment. Is there a good, documented way to do it?

Currently I'm depending on existence of environmental variable LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT which was described in the [Exploring The AWS Lambda Runtime Environment](https://alestic.com/2014/11/aws-lambda-environment/) blog post which feels wrong.

Comment: You just want to know if the code ran? do you require notifications? Do you want to know all the time, or just check somewhere that it ran?

Comment: Your current solution is what I would do. Why does it feel wrong?

Comment: I change configuration based on the environment. 

It feels wring because the environmental variable is not officially documented and probably can change without announcement.

Comment: @sumek It's officially documented http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html#lambda-environment-variables

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is a `process.env` property that you can check:

```
const isLambda = !!process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT;

if (isLambda) {
  // You're on AWS Lambda
} else {
  // Local or elsewhere
}
```

Credit to [watson/is-lambda](https://github.com/watson/is-lambda) for the discovery.

*Edit*: Official AWS source (with more env vars) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html

Comment: `const isHostedOnAWS = !!(process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT || process.env.AWS_EXECUTION_ENV);` works like a charm and doesn't rely on third party plugin. Nice trick, thanks!

Comment: if it's not obvious, the reverse is: ```const IS_LOCAL = !process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT;```

Answer (score 11):

If you want to detect whether or not your code is running in local Lambda (aws-sam-cli) or real Lambda, there's the [`AWS_SAM_LOCAL` environment variable](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/blob/b908957ae2c6150adced02903717bba780b08835/docs/advanced_usage.rst#identifying-local-execution-from-lambda-function-code).

```
function isRunningLocalLambda() {
    return process.env.AWS_SAM_LOCAL === 'true';
}
```

Comment: This environment variable does not exist for me locally

Comment: @meisel not sure what's going on, the environment variable may not be documented in the latest docs, but it's still used in the code: https://git.io/JDt9F

Comment: Perhaps it’s due to me using Serverless

Answer (score 6):

The best way to handle this is to track it yourself.  In particular, you can set a global variable or environment variable after the lambda entry point.  For example, in node.js:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    process.env['LAMBDA_ENV'] = 'true';
    ...
};
```

Comment: I like that solution. Thanks!

Comment: With this approach there's no way to distinguish between a live AWS Lambda environment or a local environment.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a Lambda environment faker, like the excellent [lambda-local](https://github.com/ashiina/lambda-local) package, checking against e.g. LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT doesn't work.

Use this instead:

```js
const isLambda = Boolean(process.env['AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME']);
```

Comment: Perhaps maybe this is actually desired...?  :P  The faker's intentionally shouldn't be setting all these values, so you can detect if you're ACTUALLY in lambda, eh?  :)

Comment: @Farley exactly, a local environment is not a AWS Lambda environment.

Comment: great for my usecase.

Answer (score 2):

When using the **Serverless Framework** to invoke a function locally, you can check the `IS_LOCAL` environment variable:

```
const isRunningLocally = () => process.env.IS_LOCAL === 'true'
```

Comment: This did not work for me, `IS_LOCAL` env var is `false`, even if I run serverless using `yarn run offline`

Answer (score 2):

I actually use

```js
const isAWSLambda = process.env.PWD?.startsWith(
  "/var/task"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something that might be resilient to working from a Docker container, too. There is a list of Lambda environment variables (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html), but many of them wouldn't necessarily be relevant in that context. However, AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME appears to be universal. I can confirm that variable is exposed/defined even in Docker-based handlers.